# matlab bar groups centered at specified location on the x-axis

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

Suppose one would like to plot 2 sets of data with unequal number of elements

```
X=[1.1 1.4 1.2 1.1];
Y=[1.4 1.4 1.1];
```

I can use boxplot

```
boxplot([X Y],[1 1 1 1 2 2 2])
```

to plot these, however
there is no function like this for bar. i.e. I would like to plot
the bars for each value of X and each value of Y but the values
in X should cluster together and should be away from the bars in Y.
Ideally In addition to the group, one would also like to specify a third parameter
which would specify where on the x-axis should the bars be centred (say in my case [2 11]-- one value for each group).

Does anyone have such a function?
I've checked matlabcentral and haven't found what I'm looking for.
thanks
L

Comment: You may be interested in my function [distributionPlot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23661-violin-plots-for-plotting-multiple-distributions-distributionplot-m), which rotates the histograms for X and Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
X=[1.1 1.4 1.2 1.1];
Y=[1.4 1.4 1.1];
a = [2 11] - 1;

bar((1:numel(X))+a(1), X, 'b')
hold on
bar((1:numel(Y))+a(2), Y, 'r')
hold off
set(gca,'XTickMode','auto')
legend({'X','Y'})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a hack, but it may be good enough for starters:

```
X = [1.1 1.4 1.2 1.1]
Y = [1.4 1.4 1]
Y(end+1) = NaN
bar([X; Y])
```

If you want to change the spacing, you can play with the locations of the `NaN`'s.

[image]